# How to connect to a Server Socket is running in Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

Actually I have created an android application. In that I have created SERVER SOCKET and listening to clients in some valid port (7000).

Then I have created Client Android application. Then connected to the server through IP 10.0.2.2 and port 7000. If the client is running in the same PC means am able to communicate. It's working fine.

Suppose If I will run my Server Android Application in one Server(IP 10.220.x.x). Here the server application is running in Android Emulator. The IP of PC is - 10.220.x.x.
After that I did corresponding change in the Client Application (changed the IP Address 10.0.2.2 to 10.220.x.x) and did the port forwarding in the Server PC. Now am running the Client Application in another machine.

But the client is not able to connect to the server.

I don't know why? 
Can anyone help me on this???

Comment: I don't know either. Any chance you could post some relevant code? Or is this just a guessing game?

Comment: It's just a client server application. Here both are android applications. Both are running in different machines. If I will run both in the same machine its working fine. When the client app is running in the same machine the IP is String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2";. But When I run the client app from another machine the ip is String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.13";

Comment: @Sathish could you solve it? I'm guessing the problem is that 10.220.x.x is your public IP address, which you shouldn't be using on your local network to connect.